# Get last N entries and order by ascending

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building a simple message box. Each message belongs to a conversation. What I'm trying to do is get the last 5 messages in the conversation and order them by ascending.

**InboxController.php**

```
public function messages($hashedId)
{
    $conversation = Conversation::where('hashed_id', $hashedId)->first();

    $messages = Message::where('conversation_id', $conversation->id)
        ->latest()
        ->take(5)
        ->get();

    $messages->orderBy('created_at','asc');


    return MessageResource::collection($messages);
}
```

**Error**

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sortBy` function. Collection doesn;t have an function named orderBy.

```
$collection->sortBy('created_at');
```

Reference:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function messages($hashedId)
{
    $conversation = Conversation::where('hashed_id', $hashedId)->first();

    $messages = Message::where('conversation_id', $conversation->id)
        ->take(5)
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->get();

    return MessageResource::collection($messages);
}
```